# Manipulate response via controller to force no cache

Tags: php, zend-framework2, response

I have an ZF2 PHP app and i want my page never put in cache and force the browser to get a new one each time.

First : how manipulate response through controller (ZF 2.4) ? My search fall on older version, often the 1.x and so one. Maybe i miss a thing.

Second : have you an advice about the 'browser never cache' manipulation to do ? On php.net they are a lot of solution but in pure PHP, maybe you know a good way with ZF2.

Thanks, have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the headers through the response object as follows from a controller action:

```
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
```